# How can I use this code on remote computer

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to use this function to monitor BSOD remotely I know I have to add a parameter of computername just not sure where

```
Function Get-BSODInfo{
try {
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview.zip" -OutFile "$($ENV:Temp)\bluescreeview.zip"
    Expand-Archive "$($ENV:Temp)\bluescreeview.zip" -DestinationPath "$($ENV:Temp)" -Force
    Start-Process -FilePath "$($ENV:Temp)\Bluescreenview.exe" -ArgumentList "/scomma `"$($ENV:Temp)\Export.csv`"" -Wait
 
}
catch {
    Write-Host "BSODView Command has Failed: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
 
$BSODs = get-content "$($ENV:Temp)\Export.csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Header Dumpfile, Timestamp, Reason, Errorcode, Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3, Parameter4, CausedByDriver | foreach-object { $_.Timestamp = [datetime]::Parse($_.timestamp, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture); $_ }
Remove-item "$($ENV:Temp)\Export.csv" -Force
 
$BSODFilter = $BSODs | where-object { $_.Timestamp -gt ((get-date).addhours(-24)) }
 
if (!$BSODFilter) {
    write-host "Healthy - No BSODs found in the last 24 hours"
}
else {
    write-host "Unhealthy - BSOD found. Check Diagnostics"
    $BSODFilter
    exit 1
}
}
```

Comment: according to the official site (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) the switch `bluescreenview.exe` is `/ComputersFile` which expects a file (list of computernames or ip addresses)

Comment: You can invoke the entirety of the script as a command in a script block, or you can also save it as a .ps1 and use `-filepath` to run it against another computer with a specific computer name

Comment: Who would I do that? I have the script created is  "-filepath" I have to place within the script? @AbrahamZinala

Comment: Can you try the following: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName DC1 -ScriptBlock ${Function:Get-BSODInfo}`

Comment: Ok, @AbrahamZinala that might work as it works on my machine I'll check on a remote one. Is there a way to have it like this:

Get-BSODInfo -computername

How would I be able to add this parameter

Comment: Invoke-Command worked thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it worked